# PHP exec() only work on command line only

Tags: php, exec

I am using PHP to backup MySQL database. But my code only works on command line (command: php index.php). If I execute it on browser, the dump file not generate. here is my code:

```
<?php
  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = 'password';
  $dbname = 'otoworks';

  $backup_file = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
  $command = "/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname | gzip > $backup_file";

  exec($command);
?>
```

My php run on apache 2.2.3, centos 6. php.ini (safe_mode = Off).

Thanks in advance

Comment: bet its a user permission issue

Comment: That's probably right. The webserver account probably doesn't have write permission to the directory it's running in. Try specifying the full pathname of the directory you want to put the backup file in.

Comment: Turn on error output and see what kind error message you're getting in the browser.

Comment: Thankyou very much to both of you. It work now!!!!

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/perform_mysql_backup_php.htm